# Spring MVC controllers not loaded

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have a problem with Spring not picking up the controller. I've used maven webapp archetype to create a project in Eclipse and it worked fine - I could access the index.jsp page. Problems started when I added Spring to the project. (context, controller, etc.)

I'm using Eclipse Mars, Tomcat 8, maven 3.3.3 and Spring 4.2.2

Here is what I see in the log (probably only third line matters):

```
Looking for matching resources in directory tree [C:\Users\dima\spring_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\cte\WEB-INF\classes\com\company\dept\demo\cte\controller]
Searching directory [C:\Users\dima\spring_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\cte\WEB-INF\classes\com\company\dept\demo\cte\controller] for files matching pattern [C:/Users/dima/spring_workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/cte/WEB-INF/classes/com/company/dept/demo/cte/controller/**/*.class]
Resolved location pattern [classpath*:com/company/dept/demo/cte/controller/**/*.class] to resources []
```

Instead of something like

```
INFO: Mapped URL path ...
```

As a result I get 404 when trying to open the web page. These are the files:

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ldap="http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/ldap/spring-ldap.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.company.dept.demo.cte.controller" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

And here is my controller:

```
package com.company.dept.demo.cte.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/pid")
public class PidController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("pidHello");
        mav.addObject("message", "hello world");
        return mav;
    }
}
```

When trying to access localhost:8080/cte/pid/hello 404 returned and the log says:

```
DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/cte/pid/hello]
Looking up handler method for path /pid/hello
Did not find handler method for [/pid/hello]
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/cte/pid/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

Thanks.

**Update:**
**WAR file is correct but for some reason when it is deployed to Tomcat controller class isn't copied.**

Comment: For starters improve your web.xml currently you state it is a Servlet Spec 2.3 application whereas you probably want, at least, 3.0 (see [here](http://www.mkyong.com/web-development/the-web-xml-deployment-descriptor-examples/) for a snippet). Next you seem to be deploying it inside/from eclipse try cleaning and redeploying the project. You also state you are using maven, have you imported a maven project or created a web project and later added maven?

Comment: what is the`url` that returns 404 error?

Comment: Is your base-package a Controller? I can see that in your dispatcherServlet.xml. Go one package behind and add an excludes-filter for the controller on it. Something like : http://pastebin.com/ahrw0jVD

Comment: It happens with me quite a lot. Cleaning the project and restarting the tomcat often loads the mapping defined in Controllers.

Comment: @M. Deinum , thanks for Servlet spec fix. There was a mess, however fixing it didn't resolve a problem. I'm now using 3.1 across project. I've used maven maven webapp archetype to create a project from within Eclipse. The archetype itself worked well and displayed the JSP page. The problem started after I added Spring to the project (xml, controller, etc.)

Comment: I've tried setting base package on different level. By the way, I only have one java class in the project - a controller. Exclusion didn't do the trick.

Comment: please show us the URL that returns status 404

Comment: Are you sure your controller isn't called? Or is it the JSP that cannot be found? Also which directory is your controller located in and are you sure it is exported when deploying it to the server?

Comment: I've updated the question with URL example. I see that dispatcher is called when request comes in, but since no controller is mapped, the dispatcher returns 'page not found'. I can access the index.jsp (root of cte.war). Controller is located in WEB-INF\classes\<package name>

Comment: So I was checking the war file and the class was there. Now I browsed the actual tomcat folder and the controller is not deployed while full directory structure is created.

Answer (score 2):

Is it your full web.xml , Because you have to add your dispatcher servlet reference to web.xml , Like below -

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Not helped. Log looks essentially the same. "Resolved location pattern [classpath*:com/company/dept/demo/cte/controller/**/*.class] to resources []"

Comment: That is basically configuring the default explictly, and won't help to resolve the issue.